# Open a .dir file using any python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, utf-8, console.dir

I have a file with `.dir` extension. I tried opening it but getting unknown/unreadable characters. I also tried opening it using python and java but not able to get the correct encoding/decoding for the characters in file. Can someone help me in this or provide some other application in which I can open this file?
I have tried the below code in python but getting unreadable characters:

```
with open(file_name, "rb") as binary_file:
    data = binary_file.read()
    dec_str = data.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
    print(dec_str)
```

Comment: are you sure it's a text file?

Comment: Did you have a look at it in a text editor, like Notepad++?

Comment: Did you look up the file extension on the web? Hint: Adobe Director.

Comment: You should try to run `file /path/to/your/file` in order to get the encoding of the file. Have you just tried to `cat` the file to read it's content in a shell ? Does that work ?

Comment: Why would one use JavaScript console.dir() to create a file instead of using JSON? And why is it tagged Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lovely chardet package to infer file encoding.

```
import chardet

with open(file_name, "rb") as binary_file:
    data = binary_file.read()
    enc = chardet.detect(data)
    dec_str = data.decode(enc['encoding'], errors='ignore')
    print(dec_str)
```

See official [docs](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) for details.